# Evaluation of $\cos\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How do you evaluate the following?

$$\cos\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]$$

To me the cosine of an arc cosine is just the value, which would be $3/4$.

Comment: Please improve formatting and fix tags.

Comment: Is your question $cos(arccos(\frac{3}{4}))=?$ ?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial to help you format your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is a fact that $f \circ f^{-1}(x)=x$ which is [Identity Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function).

Comment: @RowanS Actually $\cos^{-1}$ can be extended beyond the range $-1$ to $1$ with complex analysis. The above is completely valid.

Comment: @RowanS  $\cos$ is periodic, but $\arccos$ isn't, thus $\cos(\arccos(x))=y \implies x=y$. Perhaps you were thinking of $\arccos\circ\cos$?

Comment: You are both correct.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to draw a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse$=4$, base$=3$.

So we have angle between hypotenuse and base, $\theta=\arccos\frac34$.

So in the same triangle, $\cos\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]=\cos\theta=\frac34$